# Why does the moderator interface claim this question was closed by Community while it wasn't?

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, community-user, waffle-bar

When a post is flagged, ♦ moderators can see which previous actions on the post have been taken by moderators. I was rather surprised that the waffle bar for [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/292534/18673) showed that [Community](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (indeed, a bot account with ♦ powers) closed the question as opinion-based, while the banner clearly shows it was closed by five regular users:

[image]

Related: when a user chooses to leave anonymous feedback in the First Questions queue, a comment is posted by Community and that is also shown as one of the "Previous moderator actions". Perhaps it's best to ignore the Community user altogether when populating this dialog?

Comment: FWIW if you go into the timeline you'll also see that Community-friend "cleared" the close votes, so I'd assume it's an artefact of some specific part of the close action. If a normal mod closes a question, their account is credited with clearing the votes