# Don't count automatic review comments posted by the Community user as the "previous moderator action" on a post, as they are triggered by normal users

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, community-user, flag-dashboard

On moderator dashboard each item can contain a last moderator's reaction. That helps a lot prior handling that item by another moderator. But sometimes it's confusing (image taken from SO in Russian):

> [image]

On the image above last moderator's action is "added comment". Actually, comment was posted by the regular user from review queue and authored by Community user, who is considered by system as a moderator.

Currently, this behavior results in actions taken by actual moderators being displaced by these comments. The view should always show actions performed by real moderators or the system in response to automated actions, not actions taken by normal users and simply attributed to the Community user.

Such type of reaction should not be considered as a "moderator action". Probably the easiest way to fix this here is to not treat Community user as a moderator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is as-designed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel broken design should be fixed, don't think so? Or it isn't broken at all?

Comment: A *bug*, strictly speaking, is when something doesn't work as it's designed. If something does work as it's designed, even though the design is flawed, it's not, strictly speaking, a bug.

Comment: Correct, many people think downvotes are a bug, for example.

Comment: It is a platform moderating action whose aims to protect the user's identity, therefore being properly attributed to the Community moderator

Comment: @AugustoVasques True, but since the actual action is by a normal user, it shouldn't displace an action taken by an actual moderator. For instance, a moderator may have edited it and the user rolled the edit back.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. My mistake, I didn't realize this [bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) has no moderator status.

Comment: @AugustoVasques It does have moderator status. It casts binding votes in many cases. The "Mod" mark is hidden, but it is, internally, a moderator.

Comment: My point is that you may have a hard time convincing people that this design is broken, because it seems that there was conscious reasoning behind it at the time.

Comment: @Sonic Summarizing: Community user is a moderator, but not listed as moderator and doesn't have a "mod" badge, but internally it's a moderator. Then, should we consider mod-dashboard as an internal tool that must reflect internal status of Community user? If not, I think the current question should be tagged as [tag:bug], not a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Well, some Community user actions are useful to list as the last mod action, such as being deleted by the Roomba scripts if the post has recently been undeleted by the community so a mod can tell if it'll be re-deleted, and various other actions.

Comment: Related: [Why does the moderator interface claim this question was closed by Community while it wasn't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367924/295232)